# How to get the assigned property outside the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am getting undefined in printing obj to the console. How to access the answer outside the function??

```
        var obj;
        d3.json("country.json",function(error,answer){
             obj = answer;

          });
        console.log(obj);
```

Comment: `d3.json` is asynchronous - you can access and use the value inside that callback

Comment: Didn't get what you wanna say??

Comment: the code in the callback (`obj = answer;`) is called asyncrhonously - you can't access it (reliably) outside that asynchronous callback